# Improper table layout when applying display:block to table cell td

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a triangle (using CSS border and :before) to the corner in a highlighted table cell. If I use the default display:table-cell, it won't correctly add to the corner of the cell, but to the corner of the table. So I use display:block for that table cell.

Here's the code:

```
.cell-highlighted-triangle {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.cell-highlighted-triangle:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #510FAD;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

And to highlight a table cell I use this: 
    td class="cell-highlighted-triangle"

However, this is the result, which shows that Highlighted Column Cell 2, 3, 4 are all clamped into Column 2.

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-wUJrlaeugAI/T7UEbCdbA2I/AAAAAAAAAJM/_iu9ZxHrwGc/s519/pic.png

Thank you very much for helping me! Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try display: inline-block; should act like a mix between inline and block!

Comment: umm I have tried but the result looks worse: The 3 cells now are in 1 cell only (has height = ordinary height but width = 1/3 ordinary)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add property in style: content: "";

```
.cell-highlighted-triangle:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: #510FAD;
    border-style: solid;
}
```